# How to handle ClearKey DRM content on a custom receiver (Chromecast)?

Tags: javascript, casting, chromecast, google-cast, drm

I'm trying to create a custom chromecast receiver that is able to play clearkey protected content. How can i use the clearkey from the receiver side to achieve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may find that this actually 'just works' - Clearkey DRM contains the key, or a URL to the key in the clear, in the stream itself and should be supported as standard on a Google Cast device, I believe.

If not, or if you want to send the key or license URL anyway, you can add this in custom data that you send to the receiver - see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66580383/334402

Google provide information on this here: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/media/streaming_protocols?hl=en#drm

Specifically for your case:

> For media content that has its DRM license (and key URL) stored in their manifest (DASH or HLS), the Cast SDK handles this case for you. A subset of that content requires a licenseUrl which is needed to obtain the decryption key. In the Web Receiver, you can use PlaybackConfig to set the licenseUrl as needed.

Comment: If i send the key to the receiver, how can i handle and use it on the receiver.

Comment: Updated the answer - I would first test by simply sending the media URL and check if the receiver can simply use the clearly information there.